# why my program's result didn't seem correct with counting avg for per 30 days and for leap year?

Tags: python

this is my code for specified leap year condition:

```
import random
f = open('yearlystep.txt','w')          #write random steps for one year
for y in range(366):
    x = random.randint(0,1000)
    f.write(str(x)+'\n')
f.close()

f = open('yearlystep.txt','r')
total = 0
count = 0
for x in range(12):
    count+=1
    if count % 2 == 0 and count!=2:
        num = 30
    elif count == 2:
        num = 28
    else:
        num = 31
    for y in range(num):
        r = f.readline()
        total += int(r)
    avg = total/num
    total = 0
    
    print(avg)

f.close()
```

and this is my code for count per 30 days in one year:

```
for x in range(12):
   for y in range(30):
        r = f.readline()
        total += int(r)
   avg = total/30
   total = 0
    
   print(avg)

f.close()
```

unexpected output (on up is per 30 days and down is leap year specified with 28 days in Feburary):
[image]

i tried to compared them with the same months in 30 days and i thought they should be get the same result as i specified the condition for each number with no reminder which is even number that divided by 30 as you can see in my code figure 1. i don't understand why all of them looks completely different as some of them are supposed to be the same. is there i did something wrong with my logic or my code? can anyone explain to me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect any of the averages to be the same. Think about the first few months, and think about which rows will be read and summed to produce each average.

```
Leap Year Version 
Jan:   0-30   (first 31)      
Feb:   31-59  (next 29)       
Mar:   60-90  (next 31)       
Apr:   91-120 (next 30)       

Naive Version
Jan:   0-29   (first 30)
Feb:   30-59  (next 30)
Mar:   60-89  (next 30)
Apr:   90-119 (next 30)
```

As you can see the rows read for each month are not identical for any month, and so you will most likely get different averages (unless by some coincidence the random numbers generated result in equal averages).

I have not done all the months, but hopefully you can see that as the months continue the rows read will continue to be out of sync.

**Note:** August (the 8th month) has 31 days, so that is something that you need to address in your algorithm.